# How to calculate the number of subgroup of a group whose order is 24?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

$G$ is a group whose order is 24. And $G$ has 8 elements whose order are 3. How many subgroup does $G$ have?

I cannot come up with any method to use the condition that "$G$ has 8 elements whose order are 3".

Could anyone please help me work it out?

Comment: That's means that you have $8$ subgroups right there. It also limits which of the [$15$ groups of order $24$](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_24) you are working with. But I assume it was meant to be used in a more analytical way, and not so much brute-force.

Comment: The link you provide is very informative, but I want to find the solution in mathematics. Now the only theorem I could think of is Sylow's theorem to deal with this kind of problem. But it does not help to calculate the number of all subgroups.

Comment: @Arthur you can't have 8 subgroups of order 3 by Third Sylow theorem.

Answer (score 1):

If G has $8$ elements of order $3$ it has four subgroups of order $3$ (each contains two elements of order $3$). By Sylow's theorems these four subgroups are permuted transitively by conjugation by elements of $G$, so the action by conjugation gives you a transitive subgroup of $S_4$. You can do quite a lot with this information for a start.